# Selenium doesn't quit on KeyboardInterrupt (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to close Firefox instance that my app has opened when user interrupts the program. But selenium doesn't close the window. Here is a sample code that shows the problem:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

try:
    while True:
        driver.get("https://google.com")
        time.sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Quitting")
    driver.quit()
    print("Done")
```

When I hit Ctrl+C, I see "Quitting" printed on the console, a few moments later, I see "Done" printed to the console and program ends. But firefox window remains open. How can I solve this issue?

Edit:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

try:
    for i in range(5):
        print("Looping")
        driver.get("https://google.com")
        time.sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Quitting")
    driver.quit()
    print("Done")
driver.quit()
print("After loop and stuff")
```

This won't work neither. If you wait the loop out, browser closes successfully. But if you hit Ctrl+C in the middle of the loop, browser remains open.

Comment: try sending driver.close first... (try/catch it.. if you get an exception use driver.quit... if exception is not caught use driver.quit)... I think part of the problem though is the semi-async nature of the driver/wire protocol.  It doesn't like to be quit while it is still running tasks.  For cancelling tasks I use another thread which sets a bool to break existing loops first.  (It's not immediate...)

Comment: for the .get the driver is going to be waiting for pageload state to be returned, for instance... you have to let that communication happen (or not happen).

Comment: @pcalkins I thought of that too. So I carefully hit Ctrl-C when code was in `time.sleep(5)` part. That didn't change the result. I also tried using `close()` before `quit()`. Results were the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a research with this issue and check all possible resource available on Stackoverflow and Selenium discussion forum on github.

Same issue has raised [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6826) and closed later on due to no proper solution. You can check details here. This issue specific to Windows and firefox. It is working fine on MAC OS. The main reason I get to know it happening due to Geckodriver is getting crash, here you can check that [geckodriver-logs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/files/2858960/geckodriver.log)

They have tried with Latest Python bindings and latest Geckodriver too. No clean solution is available instead a workaround with killing `firefox.exe` process generated by Firefox driver.

Please have a look.

```
    tasklist = check_output(["tasklist", "/fi", "imagename eq firefox.exe"], shell=True).decode()
    currentFFIDs = re.findall(r"firefox.exe\s+(\d+)", tasklist)

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts, executable_path='./bin/geckodriver.exe')

    tasklist = check_output(["tasklist", "/fi", "imagename eq firefox.exe"], shell=True).decode()
    firefoxIds = set(re.findall(r"firefox.exe\s+(\d+)", tasklist)).difference(currentFFIDs)

 # do your stuff

    try:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()

        # Could't close the driver via normal means-- Force Close #
        except:
            taskkill = 'taskkill /f '+''.join(["/pid "+f+" " for f in firefoxIds]).strip()
            check_output(taskkill.split(), shell=True)
            print("\nHAD TO FORCE-CLOSE FIREFOX", flush=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `with` statement in you code, details can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

with driver:
    while True:
        driver.get("https://google.com")
        time.sleep(5)
```

If you want to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` or/and `SystemExit`, you can find useful information [here](http://effbot.org/zone/stupid-exceptions-keyboardinterrupt.htm).

I tested my code and code below in terminal, and Firefox quite as expected:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

try:
    for i in range(5):
        print("Looping")
        driver.get("https://google.com")
        time.sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("quitting: KeyboardInterrupt")
finally:
    driver.quit()
    print("Done")
```

Comment: That didn't work. I tried both using `with` and `quit()` in `except` but it didn't work. It does work when there is no exception but when there is KeyboardInterrupt exception it doesn't quit.

Comment: Just tried in terminal and no issue. What is your my app?

Comment: I literally copy pasted your code. I executed it and hit Ctrl+C after second "Looping" message. It printed "quitting: KeyboardInterrupt" and after a few seconds it printed "Done". But firefox window remained open. Is there any logs that I can share with you?

Comment: How you start the app? Is it just python file?

Comment: I'm on windows. I start it with pylauncher: `py -3 .\repro.py`. I have also tried executing it in PyCharm. The result was the same. And yes, It is the only file.

Comment: My Selenium version 3.141.0, Firefox v72.0.2, geckodriver 0.26.0. Try to update to the latest version and check again

Comment: I have the same version of everything.

Answer (score -1):

There is no terminating condition supplied for while loop.... Your while loop is running endlessly.
Keyboard interrupt block is never executed as the control doesn't get out of the while loop.

Comment: It does. Exception causes the loop to end.

Comment: It doesn't bro. Check for the sample program. Just run infinite while loop and put KeyboardInterrupt conditiy outside while block it won't work. So you better supply exit  condition inside while block.

Comment: Run the program for yourself.

Comment: I ran sample loop while putting keyboard interrupt condition in if block inside while loop. And it exited after first iteration.

Comment: Replace while with limited for loop. for example, this: `for i in range(10):`. Then hit Ctrl+C in the middle of the loop. The browser closes successfully if there is no KeyboardInterrupt exception. But when there is, it doesn't work.